# How can I implement this unitary operation using CNOT and single qubit gates?

Tags: quantum-gate

How can I implement the following unitary operation using CNOT and single qubit gates?

$$U =\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i \theta} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: This looks like a CU1 gate -> https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CU1Gate.html . Its closely related to the controlled-Rz or CRz gate

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments the gate is a [CU1 gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CU1Gate.html). For ease of visualisation I've used $\theta=2a$ as the rotation angle.

[image]

This $\mathrm{CU1}$ gate is equivalent to a controlled-Rz up to a global phase.
An Rz gate is defined to be equal to $\exp\big(-\frac{i a}{2} Z\big)$ where $Z$ is the Pauli $Z$ operator.

A $\mathrm{CU1}(2a)$ can be decomposed into the following CX and Rz operations.

[image]

If we remove the Rz from the q[0] control qubit we have an implementation of Controlled-Rz instead of CU1.

To see that this is correct consider what happens when the control qubit is in the $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$.

If the control qubit is $|0\rangle$ the first Rz will leave the state unchanged. The CX gates will also not flip the target qubit and the opposing Rz rotations on the q[1] target qubit will cancel out.

Can you work out what happens when the control is in the $|1\rangle$ state?